# Javacc regex to skip all characters unless a specific character found

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group, javacc

I want to skip all characters unless I find a specific characters. For e.g. for below string sequence:

```
--dfdfdffdfdfefsd@ : 
sdsdsdsadsad
hkkldjsfsdf , ! : 
%ABC-1.[0-7]
```

I want a javacc regex which skips all characters unless it finds `%ABC-1.[0-7]`.

The normal regex for this would be `.*?%ABC-1.[0-7]`, but for javacc I found something like `~[]?%ABC-1.[0-7]`. But it is not working.

Could you please suggest what should be correct javacc regex equivalent to normal regex `.*?%ABC-1.[0-7]`?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://www.eriklievaart.com/blog/javacc2.html

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the link . I had already gone through that. The real problem is that ~[]* or ~[]+ would eat up all characters until the EOF which I dont want. I want the regex to eat all characters until it finds a specific pattern like %ABC-1.[0-7]

Comment: You should ESCAPE the Square brackets. like this: .*?%ABC-1.\[0-7\]

Answer (score 1):

If you want one regular expression that matches all characters up to and including `%ABC-1.[0-7]` you can do this.

```
TOKEN { <FOO : (~[])* "%ABC-1.[0-7]" > }
```

If you want one regular expression that matches up to, but not including `%ABC-1.[0-7]`, that can't be done, since JavaCC does not allow right context to be used.  What you can do instead is this:

```
TOKEN { <CHAR : ~[]> }
TOKEN { <FOO : "%ABC-1.[0-7]" > }
```

In either case, you'll likely want to change the state after the `FOO` token is matched.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It indeed fixes my issue. But it makes the processing of file very slow (by almost 1 mins) which is not acceptable solution.Could you please help in improving the performance by not using the greedy algorithm ?

Comment: I can't see any reason either of these would be slow.